# Is the first season of Heroes self-contained?

Tags: continuity, heroes

I've been looking for a good series to watch, and my girlfriend suggested Heroes. Now I've heard that the first season is pretty good, but that the others are poorly written.

If there are some minor plot points unresolved, that's OK with me, but if there is some huge cliffhanger like in the end of Fringe season 1, and if the following seasons are not really good, I'd rather not start watching it.

Is it worth watching only the first season? Is it self sufficient? I mean, at the end of season 1, are there major plot points unresolved and/or a big cliffhanger? Please avoid major spoilers in case I decide to give it a try.

Comment: Lies! Heroes ended after season 1. These lies are being perpetuated by the same people who claim that there was a Highlander 2 and a Matrix 2 *and* 3!

Comment: What the...  This is not a "Request for lists of works or recommendations"!  Stop VTCing as that!

Comment: @SystemDown - There was Highlander 2. I can prove it because there was a Q about it on SFF.SE

Comment: Agree it's not a list but how is this not asking for a recommendation ?

Comment: @Stan - He's not asking for a recommendation. He already wants to watch Heroes, but is asking a specific question about intra season hanging plot lines.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First off, I'd like to try and dispel some of the rumours surrounding the quality of *Heroes*, since that's the basis of why you're considering stopping after the first season.

Season 2 was bad, but mostly not for the reasons believed by the people who stopped watching it.  Most of their gripes are about the last episode or two of that season, which felt too rushed and left tons of unresolved plot threads that were just dropped.

This happened because of the [2007-2008 Writers Guild of America strike](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2007%E2%80%932008_Writers_Guild_of_America_strike), which stopped the last half of the season from being written - those last few episodes *were* tacked on to give some sort of a resolution, even a bad one.  It was not, as many believe, because the writers were bad at their job.

So it seems likely they stopped watching the series after that point, in part due to the drop in quality and in part due to an [half a year with no new episodes of Heroes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Heroes_episodes#Season_2_.282007.29), an unusually long time for a series like this.

If you can forgive the dropped plots of Season 2, Seasons 3 and 4 do steadily increase in quality, to the point where Season 4 is better written than Season 1.  And its ending was intended to *be* an ending, unlike the relatively small cliffhangers to Season 1.

---

And so to directly answer the question about cliffhangers in Season 1?  What you learn about at the end of Episode 1 is resolved, but there are a couple other plot threads that aren't picked back up until later.

Two of them are easily forgettable and not very big, but one will likely bug you if you don't continue, because that cliffhanger - if left as a cliffhanger - completely invalidates the journey that two of the protagonists went on:

> Sylar isn't dead.

And in fact, that becomes a major focus in Seasons 3 and 4, and is resolved as part of the series finale.

Comment: I donno, in my job, if I stop showing up for work and, well, doing work, that's considered "being bad at my job".

Comment: @DVK I call it "not doing your job".  You can still be good at it.

Comment: @DVK Or fighting for better work conditions if you're on _strike_.

Comment: @Sebastian_H - I can may be sympathize with someone fighting when their "bad" work conditions involve black lung and being owned by company store. When the person's "bad" job conditions involve not being paid enough because you wanted a soft major like English Lit in college and aren't talented enough to sell books, then you deserve zero sympathy. Plenty of people would LOVE that person's job of scriptwriting, if it wasn't protected by a union.

Answer (score 6):

There are open questions about the fates of three (four?) major characters; other than that, I think the first season ties up most of its plot threads.

I think you could watch the first season alone and be reasonably satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely buy the the First season and it is nicely wrapped up aside from a couple of things that are more like "oh so that's where the story could go" rather than "WHAT HAPPENS NEXT??!!". There is definitely stuff of value in the following seasons, there is stuff that will make you go WTF but there's also some good character moments. I'd suggets if you can borrow those seasons from a library or friends or get it cheap at a pawnbroker or ebay, that way if it annoys you you won't feel you've wasted money.